# Rotating string, capital holds spot/small holds spot

Tags: c, string

input is a string: `HeLloWorlD` for an example,
The output should be: `DlHelLoorW`

The capital letters will hold their spots and only rotate in those spots between each other, same goes for small letters

the first letter is `H` and the next capital letter is `L`, in the rotation the letter `H` will take the `L`'s spot and `L` will take the `W`'s spot and so on, same thing for small letters

Way I did it, split the string into two strings, capital and small strings and filled the empty spots with `0`
so `smallString = 0e0lo0orl0` and `capitalString = H0L00W000D` then comes the function that should rotate them. I want to rotate between spots where there is only letters, so `smallString` becomes `smallString = 0l0el0oor0` and `capitalString = D0H00L000W`, but my function will just rotate all of the characters

```
static void rotateString ( char * a, int n)

   {
     int i, j;
     char buffer[BUFSIZ] = { '\0' };
     for ( i = n, j = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++ ) 
        buffer[j++] = a[i], a[i] = '\0' ;
     strcat ( buffer , a ), strcpy ( a , buffer);
   }
```

I know that the way it is written, it doesn't consider the `0` in anyway, but I tried to add an `if` condition, but only made things worse

Comment: It's unclear how that example input and output are related.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth edited

Comment: How about a different approach? First, walk through the input string separating it into two parts: (A) a string of uppercase letters and (b) a string of lowercase letters. Rotate the separated strings as desired. Then loop through the input string and, for each character, pick the next character from the corresponding rotated string and append it to the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to keep track of the last uppercase/lowercase character encountered and the index of the first uppercase/lowercase character encountered as you walk through the string, testing each character.

[See an example in action](https://repl.it/HLUm/0)

Note that I used some things you probably haven't been taught about yet. Hopefully that doesn't confuse you.

Comment: It is a bit complicated for my level to be honest with you, I will do my best to understand how it works.
feel free to explain it in short :) that'd be appreciated

Comment: @AhmadKhateeb The `swapHold` function is used to swap the character in the `hold` space with the character `a[i]`. If the `first` member is set to an invalid value, then it is set to the string index `i` and is never set again.

Comment: In the `rotateString` function, we have an array of two structures containing a `hold` space and a `first` index, one for capital letters and one for lowercase letters, so the first capital letter will set `first` in its structure and the first lowercase letter will set `first` in its structure. The rest of the time is spent swapping letters.

Comment: Finally, we place the last capital letter (in the `hold` space) at the index specified by `first` and do the same with the last lowercase letter. It's important to ensure that there were any capital/lowercase letters at all, which is why the value of the `first` index is verified to contain a valid value before proceeding.